# Errors when using Bigquery storage API

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using Microstrategy as our reporting tool and we connect to Bigquery through Simba ODBC.

In Simba ODBC, we have an option called "High throughput API" which uses Bigquery storage API.

[image]

When I look into the stackdriver, I can see some errors in the storage API.

[image]

I'm not sure what the errors are, and how to troubleshoot them. Could you please help?

Comment: Can you please add the attachement with the errors to help troubleshoot this

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY8nZ.png

Comment: Looking at the attach error it's not clear why the read operation is failing, Maybe because of the structure of your table? If you try another table, with a simple structure, you face the same problem? You might need to approach Simba support or Google for this specific issue.

Comment: Thanks Tamir. Where can I find more details regarding the error ? I need to know more details about the error so that I can troubleshoot. Is there a way to drill into the error details ?

Comment: In order to further troubleshoot your issue, you could look for those method calls in Stackdriver Logging and report them here. 

Try searching 'google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1.BigQueryStorage.CreateReadSession' and 'google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1.BigQueryStorage.ReadRows' using the advanced filter setting. You will find more information on how to perform this here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries

Comment: Hi Joaquim, I ran a report from Microstrategy now and checked the Bigquery storage API , the following is what I got : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmfMA.png and I do not see any logs being logged. I am not sure why. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is connection. Are you able to do a test connection to Google BigQuery successfully and have you followed any documentation? You can follow this [link](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/How-to-connect-to-Google-Big-Query?language=en_US#DSNGBQ).

Simba Driver leverages [BigQuery's Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/), please confirm your queries are Standard SQL.

Do you set the values of [Minimum Query Results Size for HTAPI](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/htapi_minresultssize.htm) and [Ratio of Results to Rows Per Block](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/htapi_minactivationratio.htm) when you enable the High-Troughput API? If not, please set them equal to the default values and try again.

If it doesn’t work, please read [Quotas & limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) of BigQuery, especially the Maximum number of table operations per day is 1,000.

If the issue persists, please provide Call Stack and Logging Info. There are instructions about how to enable [Driver-manager tracing](https://www.simba.com/blog/odbc-troubleshooting-tracing/) and enable logging for [ODBC/JDBC drivers](https://www.simba.com/resources/drivers/enable-logging-odbc-driver/).